# Redirect URL if Only if Query String is Present with .htaccess Rule

Tags: htaccess

I would like to redirect `example.com/image.png?example`, only if the `?example` query string is present, to `example.com/folder/folder/folder/new-image.png`, and then for `?example` to be removed from the end of the final URL.

I am using LiteSpeed `.htaccess` and am not sure how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you stuck on? You should at least attempt a solution (especially since you have posted several related questions on here and StackOverflow) - this could highlight a key point of misunderstanding that the answer could focus on.

Comment: I have looked everywhere. I've found similar questions, but not the same as mine.